# Alert not displaying when receiving json response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am sending a bad request on purpose to try and proc an alert. I have tried many ways to do an alert, but this seems the most concise. However, none of what I have tried has worked.
Can someone explain to me (as I am new to react native) how to make this alert show the response?

This is my code:

```
        const { name, username, email, password, device_name } = this.state;
        console.log(this.state)

        fetch('myURL', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.name,
            username: this.state.username,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            device_name: this.state.device_name
          })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsonResponse) => console.log(jsonResponse)).catch(error => {Alert.alert(error.status, jsonResponse[0])});
    };
```

here is the response data I am getting in the console log:

```
Object {
  "response": Object {
    "email": Array [
      "The email field is required.",
    ],
    "name": Array [
      "The name field is required.",
    ],
    "password": Array [
      "The password field is required.",
    ],
  },
  "status": "error",
}
```

Here is the code for the whole class:

```
import  React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, Alert} from 'react-native';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

export default class Registration extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      
      this.state = {
        name: '',
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        device_name: 'testDeviceID'
      };
    }

    submitRegistration = async () => {
        const { name, username, email, password, device_name } = this.state;
        console.log(this.state)

        fetch('myURL', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.name,
            username: this.state.username,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            device_name: this.state.device_name
          })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsonResponse) => console.log(jsonResponse)).catch(error => {Alert.alert(error.status, jsonResponse[0])});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={style.container}>
                <Text style={style.title} >Registration</Text>
                <TextInput 
                    style={style.input}
                    value={this.state.name}
                    placeholder="your name"
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    style={style.input}
                    value={this.state.username}
                    placeholder="username"
                    onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    style={style.input} 
                    value={this.state.email}
                    placeholder="email"
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    style={style.input} 
                    value={this.state.password}
                    placeholder="password"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                />
                <Button title='Register' onPress={this.submitRegistration.bind(this)}/>
            </View>
        )
    };
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 24,
        backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
        marginTop: 24
    },
    title: {
        marginTop: 16,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderColor: "#20232a",
        borderRadius: 6,
        backgroundColor: "#9bc2cf",
        color: "#20232e",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold"
      },
      input: {
        marginTop: 16,
        paddingVertical: 8,
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderColor: "#20232a",
        borderRadius: 6,
        backgroundColor: "#61dafb",
        color: "#20232a",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: "bold"
      }
});
```

Comment: There is a difference between an error while fetching data and successful fetching data that contains 'error' in one of its field, the latter won't make your code in catch execute, you need to parse response and check the status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your problem is on the promise. As the promise resolves just fine with the json data you are logging, the `catch` function is never called.

So options for you are:

1. To throw an `Error` with the json attached when you receive an error response from backend.

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((jsonResponse) => { 
    if (response.status === "error") {
        let err = new Error(response.status);
        err.response = response;
    }
})
.catch(error => {Alert.alert(error.message, error.response)});
```

2. To trigger the alert regardless of the result by using then instead of catch.

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(response => {Alert.alert(response.status, response)});
```

But you definitely need to read about promises to choose which solution to apply.

Comment: you were right! I didn't use your exact solution, but you led me to the right one. I didn't realize that I was never getting to the catch. So thank you for your help!